# Extract keypoints from sift detector

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, sift

I am using sift detector (`cv2.sift.detectAndCompute(image,None)`)to extract keypoints from an image. It returns the keypoints in form of smart pointers with shared ownership template

```
`struct cv::Ptr< T >`
```

How can i extract those keypoints in python to save them in a `csv` format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The descriptors of detected keypoints that you obtain, are in a list, for example:

```
[[ 42 218 124 ..., 159  69 207]
 [243  30  11 ...,  72  48 117]
 [ 45 201 236 ..., 223 216 232]
 ..., 
 [ 58   5 226 ..., 253 248 130]
 [ 44 110 154 ...,  93 124 154]
 [  7 235  19 ..., 122 161 169]]
```

The descriptor of the first keypoint looks similar to this:

```
[ 42 218 124  95  46 153 182 234 204   6 124 162  41  24 183  32 206  51 167  67 198 169 103 253   6  79 112 147  87 159  69 207]
```

In order to export these values to `csv` format using python, there are two ways:

1. Using [XlsxWriter](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/)
2. and [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) is another option and the most sought after method.